# Dropdown Menu CSS Not Showing with li:hover / a:hover -- No JavaScript

Tags: html, css

So, I'm not even worried about the positioning of these elements, or the styling. I'm just trying to get the  to show when I hover over the main li elements. I will post my code below, but will say first: I have tried many things to get this to work, and the only thing I've tried that does is  this:

```
.navbar:hover ul
```

The problem there is I don't want the 'Activities' and 'Food' elements to show when I hover over the entire navbar element. I want them to happen when I hover over each individual main 'li' element. I also want only the ones directly below what I'm hovering to show (not all 'Activity' and 'Food' elements at once)

Here are the things that aren't working:

```
.navbar li:hover ul
.navbar a:hover ul
.navbar > a:hover > ul
```

I have tried many more combinations than this that either result in me hovering an li element, and all the hidden elements display at once, or they don't display at all.
I could really use some help getting this to work (I've looked at various sites as well for explanations and cannot figure it out, which is why I'm here). Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

```css
nav ul {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0%;
}


/*NAVBAR*/

ul.navbar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #b52500;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*for mobile*/
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px -6px black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #b52500;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar .active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: .5px solid black;
  border-top: none;
}

.navbar .active:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar>ul {
  display: none;
}

.navbar a:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <ul class="navbar">

    <li> <a class="active" href="index.html"> Home </a></li>

    <ul>
      <li> Activities </li>
      <li> Food </li>
    </ul>

    <li> <a href="cent.html"> Centro Hist&oacute;rico </a></li>

    <ul>
      <li> Activities </li>
      <li> Food </li>
    </ul>

    <li> <a href="chap.html"> Chapultepec </a></li>

    <li> <a href="colo.html"> Colonia Doctores </a></li>

    <li> <a href="coyo.html"> Coyoc&aacute;n </a></li>

    <li> <a href="pola.html"> Polanco </a></li>

    <li> <a href="zona.html"> Zona Rosa </a></li>

  </ul>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the `li` elements and use the `+` adjacent sibling selector:

```css
nav ul {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0%;
}


/*NAVBAR*/

ul.navbar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #b52500;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*for mobile*/
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px -6px black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #b52500;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar .active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: .5px solid black;
  border-top: none;
}

.navbar .active:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar>ul {
  display: none;
}

.navbar li:hover + ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li> <a class="active" href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
    <ul>
      <li> Activities </li>
      <li> Food </li>
    </ul>
    <li> <a href="cent.html"> Centro Hist&oacute;rico </a></li>
    <ul>
      <li> Activities </li>
      <li> Food </li>
    </ul>
    <li> <a href="chap.html"> Chapultepec </a></li>
    <li> <a href="colo.html"> Colonia Doctores </a></li>
    <li> <a href="coyo.html"> Coyoc&aacute;n </a></li>
    <li> <a href="pola.html"> Polanco </a></li>
    <li> <a href="zona.html"> Zona Rosa </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked! I'm still confused as to why nothing else was. I guess I don't understand why  something like .navbar li:hover ul wouldn't work? Isn't the ul a child of the li?? Thanks so much though!